# Python, methods cause strange error in functions

Tags: python, function, debugging, class-method

When I run my program, it gave an error as usual. When I looked back at the code, I found the error a bit strange. I put `print` in the code to analyze a variable and I saw something that was total nonsense. Somehow a variable lost a value but in the code it doesn't change! I will share a sample code but same story here:

```
def f(a):
    a.remove(1)
    return a

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
print(f(list1))
print(list1)
```

in the first `print` you would expect an output as:

> `[2,3]`

and in second `print` you would expect:

> `[1,2,3]`

as it didn't change in the main code. Well it turns out the output is like this:

> ```
> [2, 3]
> [2, 3]
> ```

In my program, I went nuts trying to solve it. I debugged it and I saw that the variable changes in a function similar to `f()`. I thought that since in a function the program would run in *scope* level, it wouldn't influence a *global* variable like `list1`. So is this a bug in python or should I avoid using methods in functions?

By the way, I solved the problem by editing like:

```
def f(a):
    x = list(a)
    x.remove(1)
    return x

list1 = [1,2,3]
print(f(list1))
print(list1)
```

for some reason `x=a` wasn't enough so I used `x=list(a)`

Comment: No, this is how it always works. `a` is a *local reference* to an object that also has a global reference

Comment: no, we don't ecpect that. Because you are pasing reference to the list to your `f()` function. Any modification in the list outside or inside the function will reflect everywhere

Comment: `a.remove(1)` *mutates* `a`. Such code, well, mutates `a`.

Comment: Read the following to get a handle on how python variables work: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: `x=list(a)` creates a copy. More idiomatically: `x = a[:]`

Comment: Besides being a duplicate, this is a very good question. It includes a good statement of the problem, the actual code used, the actual **and** expected outputs, and even an attempt at fixing the problem!

Comment: Thanks for answering, i learned additional information about methods.